# How to setup jar configs in databricks for redis connections

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, spark-redis

I have installed the following jar in databricks `"com.redislabs:spark-redis_2.12:2.5.0"`. And trying create a spark session with the respective authentications

Below is the code where I create a spark session with creds

```
redis= SparkSession.builder.appName("redis_connection").config("spark.redis.host", "hostname").config("spark.redis.port", "port").config("spark.redis.auth", "pass").getOrCreate()
```

But when I try to save it using the follwing code

```
df.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").option("table", "velocity").option("key.column", "name").option("ttl", 30).save()
```

This throws me the following error.

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host localhost:6379
```

It obviously mean to connect to **localhost** rather the **hostname** I provide. How to pass the jar configuration with hostnames and passphrase in databricks to validate the connection.

Comment: are you executing this code in the notebook?

Comment: Yes I am executing the following code. If I am doing something wrong, please let me know

Answer (score 3):

Most likely databricks picks up the wrong spark session that doesn't have config parameters set.
You may try two options:

1. Set `spark.redis.host`, `spark.redis.port` and `spark.redis.auth` in Databricks cluster configuration. Go to cluster -> edit -> Advanced Options -> Spark -> Spark Config
2. set options in the implicitly created `spark` session with `spark.conf.set("spark.redis.host", "host")` and the same with other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error while ingesting data into redis through spark using similar configuration, i used host, port and auth as configuration instead of spark.redis.*, this worked for me

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
def getRedisClusterProperties(): HashMap[String,String] = {
    val properties = new HashMap[String,String]
    properties.put("host","<host>")
    properties.put("port","6379")
    properties.put("auth","<auth>")
    properties
}

df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("org.apache.spark.sql.redis").options(getRedisClusterProperties()).option("table","<table_name>").option("key.column","<column_name>").save
```